# Preserving print settings with VBA file save

Tags: excel, vba, printing, settings

The problem:  When saving a version of an Excel file with just values, the print settings for one page are seemingly reset (wiped out).  I need to preserve these settings, otherwise I have to reinsert code to set the print area, scaling, etc., in the file for a client in which we're trying to reduce/eliminate macros. The command to convert cell values to values is:

```
Sub ConvertAllSheetsToValues_inConvertToValuesModule()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    sh.Select
    sh.Unprotect
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ActiveSheet.Select
        Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone  'Remove shading
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.GoTo Reference:=Range("A1"), Scroll:=True    
'Position at top
        DoEvents
Next sh
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The code to save the workbook after "stripping" it down to the minimum number of tabs and VBA includes this section:

```
'Save Workbook
WkbName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5) & " - 
VALUES"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & WkbName & 
".xlsb", FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
```

I will (again) step through the code to see if the print settings for the sheet in question are ever wiped out, but I have not found this set of commands yet!

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

False alarm! A colleague pointed out that the convert to values code for the sheet in question could not wipe out print settings. It turned out that my print settings code had 
    On Error Goto 1
    1: Exit Sub
before continuing on to configure printer settings.

I'm not sure why (not that good at debugging yet), but apparently, VBA saw an error (although debug.print Error was blank as was MsgBox err.number) and the printer settings were never set!  I commented out the above code, put in "On Error Resume Next" and it worked.